# Rich Faces rich:clientId in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent of richfaces rich:clientId in primefaces?

Example, if I want to get the full client id of my field: username.

'#{rich:clientId('username'), how can I do this in primefaces? This is because I want to get the value of that field dynamically.

Comment: you can use a generic JSF way: like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12127017/617373

Comment: yes, but I want more generic approach because I need to pass the id  and get the component. so I really need something like rich:clientId().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
<h:form id="fm">
        <p:panel id="zzz">
            <p:outputPanel id="opa"/>
        </p:panel>
        #{p:component('zzz')}
        #{p:component('opa')}
    </h:form>
```

And i get output:

```
    fm:zzz 
    fm:opa
```

Comment: oh, sorry, i miss # character. Please try again :)

Comment: Thanks @RongNK, the problem was I'm using it as an update value and it should be update=":#{p:component('id')}", with prefix ":" :-)