# Accessing JSF nested composite component elements in JavaScript

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, composite-component

I am trying to DRY up popup windows in my JSF 2 project using composite components.

This code base uses Icefaces 3.3.0 (with their 1.8.2 compatibility layer for historical reasons), Mojarra 2.2.7, and Glassfish 4.1.

I have input.xhtml which provides a text input and uses a 2-button popup (ok/cancel), which in turn builds on the basic popup.

input.xhtml:

```
<composite:interface>
    <!-- ... -->
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="forInput" targets="theInput"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <my:popup2Buttons>
        <ice:inputText id="theInput" value="..."/>
        <script>setInputFocus("#{cc.clientId}:theInput");</script>
    </my:popup2Buttons>
</composite:implementation>
```

popup2buttons.xhtml:

```
<composite:interface>
    <!-- ... -->
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <my:popup>
        <composite:insertChildren/>
        <ice:commandButton id="OkButton"
             value="Ok"
             actionListener="..."/>
        <ice:commandButton id="CancelButton"
              value="Cancel"
              actionListener="..."/>
    </my:popup>                    
</composite:implementation>
```

popup.xhtml:

```
<composite:interface>
    <!-- ... -->
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <script>
    function setInputFocus(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).focus();
    }
    </script>

    <ice:panelPopup>
        <f:facet name="body">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <composite:insertChildren/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
    </ice:panelPopup>
</composite:implementation>
```

The popup works mostly as expected, i.e., I can enter something, the ok and cancel buttons work, and validation works as well.

What does not work is my JavaScript code that tries to focus the input when the popup opens.

When I look at the page in Firebug, I see that the input's ID is `MyForm:j_idt63:j_idt64:j_idt67:theInput`, but the JavaScript code tries to focus an element with the ID `MyForm:j_idt63:theInput`.

Why is `#{cc.clientId}` in `input.xhtml` not the correct ID that the input ends up getting later? What do I need to do to make this work?

I've seen [BalusC's hint on adding a binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124727/retrieving-other-components-client-id-in-jsf-2-0) but I don't want a binding so that the composite component can be independent of any backing beans.

Is there something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composite components are implicitly [naming containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html). I.e. they prepend their ID to the client ID of the children. This makes it possible to use multiple of them in the same view without their children causing duplicate IDs in generated HTML output.

In your specific case, you wrapped the input field in another composite which is in turn wrapped in again another composite. If you're absolutely positive that you don't need multiple naming containers wrapping in each other in this specific composition, then those (`popup2buttons.xhtml` and `popup.xhtml`) probably shouldn't be composites, but rather `<ui:decorate>` templates or `<ui:composition>` tagfiles. See also [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Coming back to the technical problem, it's caused because the `#{cc.clientId}` does not refer the ID of the nested composite component, but of the current composite component. And thus this would be off. As to the potential solution with `binding`, the answer which you found does nowhere tell that you should use a backing bean for this. The `binding="#{foo}"` code in the answer was as-is. It really works that way, without a bean property, see also [JSF component binding without bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168302/jsf-component-binding-without-bean-property). However, this construct would indeed fail when you include the same composite multiple times in the same view and thus multiple components share the same `binding="#{foo}"`. It indeed isn't supposed to be shared by multiple components, see also [What is component binding in JSF? When it is preferred to be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506679/what-is-component-binding-in-jsf-when-it-is-preferred-to-be-used)

To solve this without a backing bean, you can use a so-called backing component.

`com.example.InputComposite`

```
@FacesComponent("inputComposite")
public class InputComposite extends UINamingContainer {

    private UIInput input;

    // +getter+setter.
}
```

`input.xhtml`

```
<cc:interface componentType="inputComposite">
    ...
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    ...
    <h:inputText binding="#{cc.input}" ... />
    <script>setInputFocus("#{cc.input.clientId}");</script>
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

The alternative is to rework them into templates or tagfiles. Be careful that you don't overvalue/overuse composites.

Comment: The binding method only seems to work for inputs, but not for e.g., a `CommandButton`. Is that correct or am I missing something? When I add a `binding="#{okButton}"` attribute to a button, it does not get rendered. This was not part of the original question; I try to have a onKeyPress event handler on the input and click the ok button when the user presses enter and the cancel button when the user presses esc.

Comment: That may happen if multiple button components share the same `binding`. You should be using `binding="#{cc.okButton}"` as explained in the answer.