# Conditional validation without binding attribute

Tags: validation, jsf, binding, jsf-1.2, myfaces

I'm dealing with a legacy code base and come across a situation when it's necessary to validate a field "fieldToValidate" if some other field "otherField" has some value (otherwise field is not validated). However the field "otherField" doesn't have a binding attribute.
I can add a binding and then update code like this:

```
<h:inputTextarea id="fieldToValidate" value="#{MyBean.fieldToValidate}" 
required="#{MyBean.otherField != 'special_value'}" />
```

However there is a plenty of places where validation should be added and I don't want to modify backing beans. Is there a way to implement validation without adding "binding"?

Validation with some JS library is not a option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do **not** necessarily need to bind it to a bean property. Just omit the `MyBean.` part to bind it to the view scope directly.

```
<h:selectOneMenu binding="#{otherField}" ... />
...
<h:inputTextarea ... required="#{otherField != 'special_value'}" />
```

#### See also:

- [JSF component binding without bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168302/jsf-component-binding-without-bean-property/)
- [What is component binding in JSF? When it is preferred to be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506679/what-is-component-binding-in-jsf-when-it-is-preferred-to-be-used/)