# render column in jsf datatable first time only

Tags: jsf

as per my requirement I have to show a delete button end of row in datattable but restriction is to show only for first row, not in each row.
how to restrict it

belwo is my datatable

```
<h:dataTable id="datatable"  value="#{relationBean.languageDTOList}" var="lang">
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Relation Type Name</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{relationBean.relationName}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Value</f:facet>
    <h:inputText />
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">language</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{lang.languageName}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Delete</f:facet>

    <p:commandLink rendered="" action="#{relationBean.deleteDataTable}" immediate="true" update="@form" process="@this">
                <h:graphicImage value="../images/delete.png"  />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{relationBean.deleteId}" value="#{var}" />
     </p:commandLink>
        </h:column>
```

Bean.java its showing contents of bean

```
public List<LanguageDTO> getLanguageDTOList() {
    System.out.println("RelationBean:getLanguageDTOList:Enter");
    CountryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    try {
        CountryList.add(countryService.getCountryByCode(city));
        List<LanguageDTO> tempLangDTOlst=new ArrayList<LanguageDTO>();
        for (Country lang : CountryList) {
            LanguageDTO languageDTO = new LanguageDTO();
            for (CountryLanguage CLang : lang.getCountryLanguage()) {
                languageDTO =  new LanguageDTO();
                languageDTO.setLanguageName(CLang.getLanguage().getLanguageName());
                languageDTO.setLanguageCode(CLang.getLanguage().getLanguageCode());
                System.out.println(CLang.getLanguage().getLanguageName());
                tempLangDTOlst.add(languageDTO);
            }

        }
        setLanguageDTOList(tempLangDTOlst);
        System.out.println("languageDTOList :"+languageDTOList);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //BeanUtils.copyProperties(tempLangDTO,languageDTOList);
    System.out.println("--------------------Start -------------");
    for (LanguageDTO iterable_element : languageDTOList) {
        System.out.println(iterable_element.getLanguageName());
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------- End -------------");
    System.out.println("RelationBean:getLanguageDTOList:Exit");
    return languageDTOList;
}
```

Comment: There is only closing `</c:if>` in your code. where is the opening?

Comment: removed , was additional. I was trying to put command button in condition so that it appears only for first time, can you suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `<h:dataTable>` to the view via `binding`, which will reference an `UIData` component instance and in the `rendered` attribute just check if  [`UIData#getRowIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex%28%29) equals to `0`.

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{table}" ...>
    <h:column>
        <p:commandLink ... rendered="#{table.rowIndex eq 0}">
```

*(note: do **not** bind it to a bean like `#{bean.table}`! the code is complete as-is)*

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-binding-attribute-in-jsf-works)
- [JSF component binding without bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168302/jsf-component-binding-without-bean-property/)

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the current element is the same as the first element of your list:

```
<p:commandLink rendered="#{lang eq relationBean.languageDTOList.get(0)}"> ...
```

This would works only if `languageDTOList` is a `List`.

If you were using `p:dataTable` instead of the standard JSF DataTable, you could use the `rowIndexVar` variable to test if your are at the first iteration.

Comment: its not working, I have flexibility that I can use any commandButton or commandLink, languageDTOList is a List of type Language

Comment: also added bean method

Comment: This will fail if the OP doesn't have `equals()` properly implemented on object class behind `#{lang}`. Even then, there's a much simpler way to achieve this.