# JSF component binding without bean property throwing conversion error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

In a column of a table I've tried to bind a component value to a local scoped EL variable and later on to use that variable as a paramter:

```
        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="Enter a quantity to put into the cart" for="qty"/>
            <h:inputText id="qty" binding="#{qty}" converter="javax.faces.Number"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton value="Put into cart" type="submit"
                             action="#{shoppingCart.addToCart(product, qty)}"/>
        </h:column>
```

Where `product` is the current element of the datatable (a list of filtered or unfiltered products that are not in the cart).

Now when trying to add a product to the cart (e.g. with the quantity 12) it throws the following exception:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText@377c8b02 of type class javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText to class java.lang.Integer
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using Glassfish 4.1.1 with JSF version 2.2.12.

I'd be grateful for any ideas

**CLARIFACATION**

As pointed out by BalusC in this question [JSF component binding without bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168302) and others, `binding="#{var}"` is actually valid XHTML. This way no backing bean is needed and the declared variable is request scoped. I find this option more elegant and hence would like to stick with it.

Comment: Why do you see it as an advantage that you do not need a backing bean for this? As a matter of fact, I cannot imagine you do not have a 'product' class in the shopping cart with a member field 'qty' or similar, so the 'backing bean' is already there

Comment: I have made a correction. It's actually about creating a new ShoppingCartItem. Sorry for ambigious questioning

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `binding="#{qty}"` (which should be used to bind your input component to a Java instance of your component in a managed bean), use: `value="#{shoppingCart.quantityAsInteger}"`, or if you are working with a list of shopping cart items: `value="#{shoppingCartItem.quantityAsInteger}"`.

Apart from proper value binding this will also give you the benefit of having the quantity as part of your model. Additionally, when the `value` is bound to an `Integer`, there is no need to add a converter. JSF will take care of [`Integer` (and some other types) conversion by default](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/j2ee101302/jsf_apps/eventvalidate/sf_avc_converters.html).

So, make sure you have a managed bean containing the quantity or a list of cart items which each have a quantity. In case of a list of cart items, you will end up with something like:

**ShoppingCart.java**

```
// You will probably already have something like this for your table
private List<ShoppingCartItem> shoppingCartItems;
```

**ShoppingCartItem.java**

```
// Quantity used for binding (add getter and setter).
private Integer quantity;

private Product product;
```

**XHTML**

```
<h:column>
    <h:outputLabel value="Enter a quantity to put into the cart" for="qty"/>
    <h:inputText id="qty" binding="#{shoppingCartItem.quantity}" />
</h:column>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I cannot use binding="#{shoppingCartItem.quantity}" since there's no item at the moment. I mean an object is only created after clicking on the commandButton and thus I cannot specify a value for the item before it's even created. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: Sorry, you could add a quantity integer to `Product` for adding product. Core of your problem, as you already found out, is that you should use `value` for value binding.

Comment: In that case, use `value="#{product.quantity}"` and `action="#{shoppingCart.addToCart(product)}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `value` attribute instead of `binding` attribute in `h:inputText` and use `binding` attribute on a table component. That way you can access to the selected (clicked) row in a action method: if `binding` attribute of a table has value `#{bean.dataTable}`, you can get row data in a method like `getDataTable.getRowData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Though declaring an EL variable is valid XHTML, the component itself is bound to the variable, if using the `binding` attribute. No conversion errors are thrown when using the EL variable with the `value` attribute, like that:

```
        <h:inputText id="qty" value="#{qty}" converter="javax.faces.Number"/>
        ....
        <h:commandButton value="Put into cart" type="submit"
                         action="#{shoppingCart.addToCart(product, qty)}"/>
```

Comment: That's what I was telling you ;-)

Comment: @JasperdeVries: not completely... here he is defining a requestScoped variable that is not a field in a bean. It only exists during the request. Slightly different than your example. Also see his 'edit/clarification' to the question

Comment: Right.. now I get it. I thought it was about editing a shopping cart!

Comment: I also think it is about editing a shopping cart. But editing it in an unusual way with and 'optimization' that is imo not an optimization...